# SQL Server Connection using GPConnNet.dll for non sa user In microsoft dynamic gp

Tags: c#, dynamic, econnect

I saw [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11865354/sql-server-connection-using-gpconnnet-dll) non sa user sql connection string.

This is giving datasource name and userid and passworkd and database name. But I have doubt about datasource name :`Dynamic GP 2010`. I am bit confused using this connection string:

```
 string connection = "data source=Dynamic GP 2010;initial catalog=TWO;integrated security=False;User ID=client;Password=123";
```

This is giving error: `A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: Named Pipes Provider, error: 40 - Could not open a connection to SQL Server)`

Let me know which datasource I have to use. Is `GP datasource` name (or) `sql datasource` name.

Answer (score 2):

Econnect must use a trusted connection. You cannot pass a username and password into the connection string. To add a user that does not have sa access, add the domain user to sql server with the appropriate permissions. You will also need to configure the econnect setup to allow the user to access sql through econnect. Secondly, if you are setting this up on a SQL server that has not been setup to allow incoming connections via non-windows connection, this will need to be set up as well. This may be due to not having mixed auth mode on. [See this article to try and fix](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1719399/sql-server-2008-cant-login-with-newly-created-user)

```
string connectionString = @"Data Source=localhost; Integrated Security=SSPI;Persist Security Info=False; Initial Catalog=TWO;";
```